# Loopback: Can't find path to image

Tags: typescript, strongloop, loopback

I am using Nodemailer to send an email and with that email I want to display an image. But I keep getting this error:

> Cannot start the application. { Error: Cannot find module '../images/logo.png'

I don't think this is an issue relating to typescript because importing the image goes well, without any errors. And I already have put *.png in my globals.d.ts,  I might overlook something though.

My controller looks like this:

```
import { requestBody, post } from '@loopback/rest';
import { SendMail } from "../models/mail.model";
import logoImg from "../images/logo.png";

export class MailController {
  constructor(
  ) {
  }


  @post('/mail/acceptation')
  async sendEmail(@requestBody() obj: SendMail): Promise<SendMail> {
    return await transporter.sendMail({
      from: "agile@minbzk.nl",
      to: `${obj.to}`,
      subject: "Aanvraag geaccepteerd",
      html: `<img src=${logoImg}`
    })
  }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to put the image in the html value. Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The image src attribute should be a string with the image path, not an object.

Comment: @RafaelDuarte if I use the path to the image as a string, it will display nothing.

Comment: You need to display the absolute path to the image, for example : ```www.yourdomain.com/assets/yourImage.png``` , otherwise, the email receiver won't see the image.

Comment: @RafaelDuarte Yes that was indeed it, only problem was that Loopback didn't include non ts & js files in the build folder. So it was looking for something that didn't exist. Thanks for your help, definitely helped me.

Comment: No problem, if you found a solution don't forget to post it here, someone else might run into this post with the same problem :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a folder and also define a data-source before you run the server.

In datasource.json

```
 "storage": {
    "name": "storage",
    "connector": "loopback-component-storage",
    "provider": "filesystem",
    "root": "./server/storage/"
  },
```

and then create a folder "storage" in your server folder and then "images" folder inside your storage folder.

**References**

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Storage-component.html
- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Storage-component.html